# Super Search Query Overloads DB and Brings Down Websites

Tags: solspace, mysql, supersearch

Once a day for the past week our websites have been going down around the same time, but then slowly comes back up after 30 minutes. We've discovered it's due to a MySQL overload caused by the Super Search add-on. Below is an example of the query, but add hundreds more entry ID's to it:

> /* Super Search ct/cd search */  SELECT t.entry_id  FROM
>   exp_channel_titles t    LEFT JOIN exp_channel_data cd ON cd.entry_id =
>   t.entry_id  WHERE t.entry_id != 0     AND t.entry_date < 1415828729
>   AND (t.expiration_date = 0 OR t.expiration_date > 1415828729)    AND
>   t.channel_id IN (7) AND t.status = 'open'    AND t.site_id IN (1)
>   /*Begin subids statement*/    AND t.entry_id IN
>   ('83','84','85','88','89','90','91','92','93','94','95','96','97','98','99','100','102','103','104','105','160','161','163','185','187','193','196','203','209','220','221','225','227','230','231','232','233','234','235','239','240','249','301','301','301','301','301','301','316','317','320','321','322','323','324','325','326','327','328','329','330','332','333','334','335','336','340','341','342','343','344','345','355','359','360','365','366','368','369','370','371','379','380','381','382','384','385','386','391','392','393','394','395','398','407','408','409','410','411','413','415','416','418','419','423','434','435','436',
>
> <---then skipping to the bottom of the query-->
>
> 44301','44302','44308','44318','44321','44322','44324','44326','44335','44336','44337','44338','44339','44340','44343','44346','44347','44348','44351','44357')
>   /*End subids statement*/   ORDER BY t.sticky DESC, t.entry_date DESC,
>   t.entry_id DESC

What's causing this and how can we fix it? It has started to become a big issue lately.

Comment: To confirm, this is the query generated by the addon itself? Also, can you post the template code being used in relation to SuperSearch itself, particularly for you results/sorting?

Comment: It appears to be a query generated by the addon. We're using Super Search in a variety of places, but none that would create a query like this. Particularly at the same time every day.

Comment: If you **turn on the output profiler** in EE, how long does this query take? There should be an execution time displayed next to the query. Make sure you cleared the Super Search cache first. Also, have you had a look at your server logs? Is that how you suspect Super Search's query? Also, as others have mentioned, template code would be great.

Comment: Looking at the server logs at the time of slowdown would be helpful. A number of things could be happening on your server (or in EE) at that specific time, which might give some insight.

Comment: It's definitely Super Search generating the query. Is it normal for it to try and pull 22,000+ IDs every 24 hours? As that looks like what's happening here.